# how to pass function parameters to prototype function

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am trying to extend the videojs plugin to add in some additional buttons but I've hit a bit of a stumbling block. I need to be able to grab the share `data-attr` attached to the video element so would like to use that new player, so I create the like button by extending Button and then I create a new button using prototype, in the `createEl method` I want to set the `data-href`, at the moment I use `player.options['shareUrl']` as this is ideally what it would be but I get player is undefined, I was wondering how I pass the player to createEl in the init?

**Example code:**

```
vjs.LikeButton = vjs.Button.extend({
  /** @constructor */
  init: function(player, options){
    vjs.Button.call(this, player, options);
  }
});

vjs.LikeButton.prototype.createEl = function(){
    return vjs.Button.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
        'id': 'video-fb-like',
        'className': 'fb-like',
        'innerHTML': '',
        'data-send': "false",
        'data-layout': "box_count",
        'data-width': "55",
        'data-show-faces': "false",
        'data-colorscheme': "dark",
        'data-href': player.options['shareUrl']
  });
};
```

Comment: where are you getting the `extend` method from...i mean what framework? And what happens inside the `Button` constructor? If `player` isn't already saved as a property then I guess you could just write `this.player = player;` inside your `init` function and refer to it later in the same way.

Comment: @basilikum  Looks like extend is from videojs core object: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/core-object.js  styler: can the videojs be compiled with closure compiler? It looks like compiler annotated code.

Comment: Does this work? `'data-href': this.player_.options_['shareUrl']`

Comment: yeah that was it, i needed to use this.player_.options.['shareUrl']